# Close dialog not visible when opened on 'duplicate' tab of close vote review

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-close

I'm reviewing Close Votes, targeting specifically Duplicate types. If I've switched to view the duplicate and then click "Close", the Close dialog does not appear. I believe it's actually being loaded in the 'question' view, since it briefly appears when I switch back to the question view. (Also clicking the close button a second time shows the "You may only load the close dialog every 3 seconds" popup, which indicates that the site thinks *it* is showing the popup even though I can't see or interact with it.)

It seems that the optimal workflow should be:

1. Read the question
2. Switch over to the duplicate and review it to see if it is a good match
3. Click close & VTC if it is.

However this bug means that I have to do an additional step to switch *back* to the question view before I VTC.

Browsers:

- Brave: Version 1.13.82 Chromium: 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Chrome: Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Windows 10 Enterprise.